# Using string interpolation in C# to print floating point values

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I'm trying to use string interpolation to print a floating point number to 3 decimal places.
`Console.Writeline( $"{3.2, 8: F3}" );` However, this is printing "F3" in a field width of 8. Why is this happening. For example, `Console.WriteLine($"{3.2M, 8: C2}");` accurately prints as $3.20 in a string field width of 8.

Comment: you need to remove the space `8:F3`

Comment: @Pac0 Didn't know C# was so strict in this regards. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space after the colon `:` causes the issue, you need to be careful about this in format strings:

```
Console.Writeline( $"{3.2, 8:F3}");  // Outputs 3.200
```

[Test it in DotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/7hWGxz)